# How to post with request parameters and json in android

Tags: android

I need to post data to **webservice** where I need to send a parameter along with `JSON object` in android . Is it possible to send both parameter and `JSON object` while posting data ?

My code is as folows:

```
nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();   
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", "abc.org"));  

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));                 
httpPost.setEntity(JSON.toString);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: try with, http://url.com/val?query=parameter then call setEntity method only once

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `setEntity()` twice like this. If your server is expecting POST content that is form-encoded, then you'll need to add your JSON object as one of the POST parameters. If your server is expecting the JSON object as the POST body, then it can't also be expecting any other parameters (this wouldn't be possible). It may be possible that it expects additional parameters in the query string part of the URL though. Check the API documentation of your server.